# Зависимые по высоте div'ы или ячейки таблицы в разном стилевом оформлении

Tags: html, css

Вот, собственно то, что необходимо сделать:
[image]

Сталкивался кто-нибудь с подобной задачей?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант с таблицами в данном случае - не самый лучший. Нашел более правильное, на мой взгляд решение (в контексте поставленной задачи) с использованием div'ов.

**[Смотреть здесь](http://jsfiddle.net/Alex83/YDYwV/)**.

Может быть для кого-то окажется полезным...

Answer (score 0):

Простая задача, конечно таблицей легче сделать но если требуются div это изврат для меня

http://jsfiddle.net/good_web_master/d7VVN/

Comment: @good, и как это сделать таблицей? не подскажите? На сколько я понимаю, необходимо нечто подобное:

    <td>1</td>
    <td>1.1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>2.2</td>

Но как теперь вычленить <td>1</td> и <td>2</td> и задать для них иное оформление?

Comment: пароль забыл на jsfiddle.

Comment: @good, ну хотя бы в ответе апдейт сделайте ...